# Finding adjoint and norm of projection

Tags: linear-algebra, projection, adjoint-operators

We consider the Hilbert space with standard inner product, $0<\phi<\frac{1}{2} \pi$. We consider the projection P:
$
P
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1-x_2cot(\phi)\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$

I need to show that $||P||=\frac{1}{sin(\phi)}$ which I tried by calculating $<Px,Px>$ but I couldn't figure it out. (I got $x_1-x_2cot(\phi)$ again)

But I'm really unsure about my reasoning here. Any help for my problems is very much appreciated :)

Comment: What is the Hilbert space in this question ???

Comment: The Hilbert space is $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: I would not have guessed that! what is $\phi$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\|P\|=\sup \{|x_1-x_2\cot \phi |\}: x_1^{2}+x_2^{2} \leq 1\}=\sqrt {1+(\cot \phi )^{2}}=\frac 1 {\sin \phi}$. [This is a consequence of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality].  You have already found the matrix of $P^{*}$. You can write $P^{*}(x_1,x_2)=(x_1,-x_1\cot \phi)$.

I have used the following: $\sup \{ax+by: x^{2}+y^{2} \leq 1\} \leq \sqrt {a^{2}+b^{2}}$ by Cauchy Schwarz inequality and the sup is attained when $x=\frac  a {\sqrt {a^{2}+b^{2}}}, y=\frac  b {\sqrt {a^{2}+b^{2}}}$ Hence, $\sup \{ax+by: x^{2}+y^{2} \leq 1\} = \sqrt {a^{2}+b^{2}}$.

Comment: How does from CZ-inequality follow that $\sqrt{1+(cot(\phi))^2}=\frac{1}{sin(\phi}$ (since it's an inequality)

Comment: The first equality I wrote is by C-S inequality. The second one: $1+\cot \phi^{2}=\frac  1{\sin \phi^{2}}$ is obvious by definition of $\cot \phi$ and the fact that $\sin ^{2}+\cos^{2}=1$.  @Rini